# Unlock Gnome 3 without mouse

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, lock-screen

When I want to unlock my screen in a Gnome 3 session, I have to use my mouse to "drag up" the screen and uncover the password input.
I would prefer to not use the mouse for that action since I am using a Notebook and that kind of gesture is really annoying.

Answer (score 8):

And after some more trying, <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> both work fine, the former also allowing to "cancel" the unlock.